# jQuery adding a function to a link question

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically created table which in the last `<td>` there is a hidden `<div>` which is shown when the user hovers over a link in the `<td>`. That all works fine but there are several links in the div that I want to fire a function based on the id of the link concat'd with an string captured from a `<td>` from the parent row. I can capture the the variables I need from the id and `<td>` but something is wrong with the click function I have created.

I monitored the function in FireBug and the function appears to be firing on all of the links instead of the one that is clicked. Here is my working code:

```
function fixLink() {
           $('a.batchMatchLink').click(
             function() {
                 var r = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
                 var x = $(this).attr("id");
                 var a = $(r).find('td:nth-child(6)').text();
                 var st = x + "." + a;
                 fireLink(st);
             }
            );
       }

       function fireLink(st) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "AjaxWcf.svc/MatchBatch",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data: st,
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(msg) {
                   alert("Entry has been updated");
                   },
               error: AjaxFailed

           });
```

Why are all of the links firing?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's not obvious, try console.log( $('a.batchMatchLink') )

Comment: You seem to be missing a curly brace in here?

Comment: `var r = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();` Why??
Use a better selector like `var r = $(this).parent(".actual")`

Comment: @nvl - You mean `$(this).closest(".actual");` :)

Comment: @wali - can you supply more code, like your (x)html please. You are missing a curly brace, but I suspect this is just a posting issue

@nvl - .parent([expr]) should work too.

Comment: @Nick: both would work, right? :)

Comment: @nvl - There are subtle but important differences, check it out: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @Nick: hmm.. i think `.closest()` would be more approp. here :) thanks

Comment: my apologies;
the remainder of the code is the AjaxFailed function:

 function AjaxFailed(result) {
                   alert("There was a problem updating the entry");
               }
           }

Thanks!
 Wali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you only need to cancel the click event :

```
function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var r = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
    var x = $(this).attr("id");
    var a = $(r).find('td:nth-child(6)').text();
    var st = x + "." + a;
    fireLink(st);
}
```

Comment: `return false` will also preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use live() or bind() instead of directly binding the method by name, and using event data to guess which element did fire the event.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/#passing-event-data